# Why does Assert.AreEqual(1.0, double.NaN, 1.0) pass?

Tags: .net, mstest, double, assert, nan

Short question, why does `Assert.AreEqual(1.0, double.NaN, 1.0)` pass? Whereas `Assert.AreEqual(1.0, double.NaN)` fails.

Is it a bug in MSTest (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework) or am I missing something here?

Best regards, Egil.

---

Update: Should probably add, that the reason behind my question is, that I have a bunch of unit tests that unfortunately passed due to the result of some linear algebraic matrix operation being NaN or (+/-)Infinity. The unit tests are fine, but since Assert.AreEqual on doubles with a delta will pass when actual or/and expected are NaN or Infinity, I was left to believe that the code I was testing was correct.

Comment: Microsoft bug entry: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762286/unit-test-with-assert-areequal-2-3-double-nan-0-1-passes

Comment: And the idiots closed it as "by design".

Comment: Interesting, because MS recanted and says it's now fixed: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780654/assert-equal-and-double-nan

Comment: It's a bug. You are quite reasonable to expect the test "|x-1| ≤ 0.1" to fail when x is NaN, as it does for x=3. To suggest this is user error is ridiculous.

Comment: The answers are out-of-date. If the bug has been fixed, when, and in which versions of what assembly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be careful. NaN is weird, somewhat like null in many DBMSs, and you shouldn't be comparing values to it (either directly, or with Assert.AreEqual). From the docs for [Double.NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx):

> Use IsNaN to determine whether a value
>   is not a number. It is not possible to
>   determine whether a value is not a
>   number by comparing it to another
>   value equal to NaN.

```
double zero = 0;
Console.WriteLine((0 / zero) == Double.NaN);  // prints false
Console.WriteLine(Double.IsNaN(0 / zero));  // prints true
```

You'd have to peer at the internals of Assert(double, double, double) to see what's going on, but in general, you're depending on undefined behavior relative to NaN.

Comment: The story behind my question is a bunch of unit tests that unfortunately passed due to the result of some linear algebraic matrix operation being NaN/(+/-)Infinity. The unit tests are fine, but since Assert.AreEqual on doubles with a delta will pass when actual or/and expected are NaN or Infinity, I was left to believe that my code actually worked...

Comment: I get that. On the face of it, the behavior is incorrect, and you'd be justified filing an issue on Microsoft Connect. If you like, hook up a symbol server and see how Assert.AreEqual(double, double) differs from Assert.AreEqual(double, double, double).

Answer (score 7):

> The answers are out-of-date. If the bug has been fixed, when, and in which versions of what assembly?

That's correct, it was fixed in VS2013 with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll assembly, version 10.0.0.0.  Present in the legacy GAC, c:\windows\assembly, it also has the 10.1.0.0 version.

There is a DLL Hell story here, the 10.1.0.0 version was the one used in VS2010.  It had the bug, not properly checking for Double.NaN.  Microsoft made a mistake, they fixed 10.1.0.0 but did not change the version number.  So anybody that installed VS2010 *after* installing VS2013 is going to get hurt, it is going to overwrite the DLL with the buggy version.

Unraveling DLL Hell is never that simple, but it appears from the [connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762286/unit-test-with-assert-areequal-2-3-double-nan-0-1-passes) and from the way it works on my machine that they identified the failure mode from the customer's complaint.  And provided a fix, delivered in an update.  Not clear which, after July 2014.  You'll now use v10.0.0.0, the MSTest.exe test runner and the QTAgents have a .config file with a `<bindingRedirect>` that redirects from 10.1.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 (not a typo).  Be sure to obtain the latest update, currently 4.  Look in Help + About if you are not sure what update you have installed.

For the record, the fixed code acquired specific checks for Double.NaN, it looks like this:

```
public static void AreEqual(double expected, double actual, double delta, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
    if ((double.IsNaN(expected) || double.IsNaN(actual)) || double.IsNaN(delta))
    {
        string str = (string) FrameworkMessages.AreEqualDeltaFailMsg((message == null) ? string.Empty : ReplaceNulls(message), expected.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat), actual.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat), delta.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat));
        HandleFail("Assert.AreEqual", str, parameters);
    }
    if (Math.Abs((double) (expected - actual)) > delta)
    {
        string str2 = (string) FrameworkMessages.AreEqualDeltaFailMsg((message == null) ? string.Empty : ReplaceNulls(message), expected.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat), actual.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat), delta.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat));
        HandleFail("Assert.AreEqual", str2, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hans, thorough as always. The 'dll hell' explains the inconsistencies in reproducing this bug between my colleagues' machines.

Comment: it seems that even after the "fix", `Assert.AreEqual(double.NaN, double.NaN, 0.001);` will fail. I guess I will have to write my own double assert until the next patch comes around.

Answer (score 5):

MSTest uses the following formula for the `Assert.AreEqual<double>(expected, actual, delta)` method:

```
if (Math.Abs(expected - actual) > delta)
    Assert.HandleFail("Assert.AreEqual", ...)
```

The operation reduces to `double.NaN > delta`, which returns true in this case.  Or undefined.