# double.NaN Equality in MS Test

Tags: c#, mstest, nan

Why am I getting this result?

```
[TestMethod]
public void nan_test()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(1, double.NaN, 1E-1); <-- Passes
    Assert.AreEqual(1, double.NaN);       <-- Fails
}
```

What difference does the delta have in asserting NaN equals a number? Surely it should always return false. I am aware of IsNaN, but that's not useful here (see below).

Background: I have a function returning NaN (erroneously) , it was meant to be a real number but the test still passed. I'm using the delta because it's double precision equality, the original test used 1E-9.

Comment: Microsoft bug entry: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762286/unit-test-with-assert-areequal-2-3-double-nan-0-1-passes

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780004/why-do-mstests-assert-areequal1-0-double-nan-0-0-pass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Assert.AreEqual(1.0, double.NaN, 1.0) pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780004/why-does-assert-areequal1-0-double-nan-1-0-pass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Assert.AreEqual(1, double.NaN)`, it tries an equality test on the numbers and of course it fails, since `double.NaN` isn't equal to anything.

When you do `Assert.AreEqual(1, double.NaN, 1E-1)`, it has to do arithmetic on the numbers. Specifically, it computes

```
Math.Abs((double) (expected - actual)) > delta
Math.Abs(1 - double.NaN) > 1E-1
Math.Abs(double.NaN) > 1E-1 // All arithmetic with double.NaN returns double.NaN
double.NaN > 1E-1 // All comparisons with double.NaN return false (except !=)
```

which is false. It *looks* like the actual delta isn't larger than the `delta` you passed, but only since it is trying to indicate that you cannot perform the comparison.

Moral of the story: the behavior of NaN is pretty crazy (but the best some smart people could come up with). Do your best to check for NaN before performing any computations where you cannot have the error propagate up silently, like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use this test for NaN instead?

```
double.IsNaN(somenNumber)
```

Comment: Yea but I don't want my result to be NaN, if I just ran the test without debugging with an expected value, it would pass. Not good.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: [Why does Assert.AreEqual(1.0, double.NaN, 1.0) pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780004/why-do-mstests-assert-areequal1-0-double-nan-0-0-pass)

Edit:

there is definitely a bug in `Assert.AreEqual`. in VS 2008's Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework it's coded as

```
if (Math.Abs((double) (expected - actual)) > delta)
{
    // report error
}
```

As in your case `Math.Abs((double) (expected - actual))` is a `double.NaN`, the comparison yields `false` :-)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. The OP of that question seems to have got the problem doing exactly the same thing as me, weird.